# Mailgun Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, mailgun

I installed [Mailgun for Laravel](https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun/). I then tried to run the example

```
$data = [];
Mailgun::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

But I got the following error:

```
"Argument 1 passed to Bogardo\\Mailgun\\Mailgun::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\\View\\Environment, instance of Illuminate\\View\\Factory given, called in /Users/koushatalebian/CLG/CL2G/app/vendor/bogardo/mailgun/src/Bogardo/Mailgun/MailgunServiceProvider.php on line 33 and defined"
```

What is going on?

Comment: I'll try to update the package to make it compatible with Laravel 4.2 and release a new version this weekend. I'm the maintainer of the package.

Comment: If you upgrade to Laravel 5, it has [mailgun support out of the box](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 4.2, Please use `Illuminate\View\Factory` instead of `Illuminate\View\Environment`.

Bogardo mail gun package pointing wrong file.

```
/Users/koushatalebian/CLG/CL2G/app/vendor/bogardo/mailgun/src/Bogardo/Mailgun/MailgunServiceProvider.php
```

```
View / Pagination Environment Renamed

If you are directly referencing the Illuminate\View\Environment class or
Illuminate\Pagination\Environment class, update your code to reference Illuminate\View\Factory and
Illuminate\Pagination\Factory instead. These two classes have been renamed to better reflect their
function.
```

**Edit:**

You can use the correct class by editing the following file:

`vendor/bogardo/mailgun/src/Bogardo/Mailgun/Mailgun.php`

in Line 5:

remove `use Illuminate\View\Environment;` and use `use Illuminate\View\Factory;`

in line 53:

remove

```
public function __construct(Environment $views)
{
    $this->views = $views;
}
```

use

```
public function __construct(Factory $views)
{
    $this->views = $views;
}
```

Hope this will fix.

Comment: Where do I change this?

Comment: I am afraid, you have to change code many places as your package is not for Laravel 4.2.In addition, if you update the package it will change the changes as well. My suggestion is use Laravel's default mailgun driver.

Comment: However, I can show you the changes. please check my edited answer after few mins.

Comment: There is indeed native support for Mailgun in the new 4.2 Laravel release, though the package adds some Mailgun specific features like tagging, and tracking.